# Machine learning - Train medical image

Tags: tensorflow, medical

I am trying to create Deep Neural Network based classifier for chest x-ray to check there is TB or not. I read that transfer Learning technique can be used for this using inception model v3. My question is inception model is created by training with imagenet(physical object) right? How can this be used for medical image training?

Answer (score 0):

One intuition is that physical objects and medical images do share some similarities especially in low-level features such as edges, curves and small object regions.

Experiments indicate that pretraining a network on ImageNet can benefit most computer vision tasks even if the images from the target domain look very different from what are in the ImageNet.

To achieve best performance, you can use a pretrained network from Imagenet and fine-tune the last layer or all layers with small learning rates on your dataset.